# How to select Amazon Timestream in Grafana as data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-timestream

By following [this document](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-timestream-datasource/) and [tutorial video at that time](https://youtu.be/pilkz645cs4?t=509), when I tried to set AWS Timestream as data source in Grafana, but I could not find it.
I use free account.
Could you tell me what the problem is?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve this issue by installing Timestream plugin.